# Typescript: generic immutable collections

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

I have the following definition (I'm using ImmutableJS):

```
declare module Immutable {
    export module Record {
        type IRecord<T> = T & TypedMap<T>;

        interface TypedMap<T> extends Map<string, any> {
            set(key: string, value: any): IRecord<T>
        }

        interface Factory<T> {
            new (): IRecord<T>;
            new (values: T): IRecord<T>;

            (): IRecord<T>;
            (values: T): IRecord<T>;
        }
    }

    export interface Record<T> {
        (defaultValues: T, name?: string): Record.Factory<T>;
    }

    export function Record<T>(
        defaultValues: T, name?: string
    ): Record.Factory<T>;
}

declare interface IState extends Immutable.Map<string, any> {
    router: Immutable.Map<string, any>;
    sessions: Immutable.Map<gameId, Immutable.List<Immutable.Record<ISession>>>;
    games: Immutable.Map<gameId, Immutable.Record<IGame>>
}
```

When I use it this way:

```
const state: IState = <IState>Map<string, any>({
    router: Map<string, any>(),
    sessions: Map<gameId, List<Record<ISession>>>({
        1: List([10])
    }),
    games: Map<gameId, Record<IGame>>()
});
```

I don't get any errors. I would expect it to complain about the this part:

```
sessions: Map<gameId, List<Record<ISession>>>({
    1: List([10])
})
```

I added the number `10` into a `List<Record<ISession>>`

Any why I don't see any errors?

Comment: The examples you have supplied don't seem complete - I can't see where the `Map` class/method is defined.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but it didn't fit in the comment box.

@Sohnee, as to your question in comment above, @ppoliani is extending the types from Immutable.js, so that's where Map (and List, and Record) are coming from.

I wonder if "this" feature of TS 1.7 is relevant to the answer: [Typescript PR for *polymorphic 'this' type*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910). I think the Immutable.js folks are still ruminating on what to do with type safety and inheritance in Records. Witness

- [proposed type tweak to improve use of Record instance in TypeScript code](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/341) and
- [Suggestion: Interface extend generic type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2225).

While they're ruminating on that, I'm ruminating on whether records are worth the type-safety challenges they present.